# How to load selected values in multiple-dropdown in update view in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new in yii. I have problem with fetching selected values in dropdown when updating the record.
I have dropdown with multiple selection of user's email.
 
When adding it is working fine, it allows me to select multiple values and can insert selected value's ids comma separated in database.
 But the problem is when i want to update the record it displays only 1 selected record.

Here is my code:

in my **View file**:

```
<div class="controls">
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'uid', $allUsers, array('class' => 'select2-me input-sel_large', 'multiple' => 'true', 'options' => array('' => array('selected' => true)))); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'uid') ?>
</div>
```

in my **Controller file**:

```
$model = new User;
$allUsers = $model->getAllUsers();
```

in my **Model file**:

```
public function getAllUsers() {
        $arr = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('userEmail,pkUserID')
        ->from('tbl_user')
        ->queryAll();
        $users = array();
        if (is_array($arr)) {
            foreach ($arr as $value) {
                $users[$value['pkUserID']] = $value['userEmail'];
            }
        }
        return $users; 
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example. Hope this help you.

```
class YourForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $uid = array(); // selected pkUserID's
}

//in action
$yourForm = new YourForm();
$yourForm->uid = array(1,2,3); // for example selected users with pk 1,2,3

$this->render('your_view', array('yourForm'=>$yourForm));

//view
/** @var CActiveForm $form */
/** @var YourForm $yourForm */
echo $form->dropDownList(
    $yourForm,
    'uid',
    CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'userEmail ASC')), 'pkUserID', 'userEmail'),
    array('empty' => '', 'multiple'=>true))
   )
```

Comment: when i am adding then that time it is working fine.. but i want to get selected values at the time of update it

Comment: @noddy  Form - $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(...) in listData build listing of users. ask what you are interested please.

Comment: i have added selected values in db comma separated. and when updating  the record i want that values as selected in dropdown

Comment: selected value gets from your $model->uid

Comment: what is instance of $model?

Comment: can you explain that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79631/discussion-between-danila-ganchar-and-noddy).

Comment: form where values will be in dropdown?